# How to compare values in one array?

Tags: c#

How can I compare elements in one array?
if the next number in the array is greater than the previous one, then transfer these two values further ... And accordingly, if this is not so, transfer them to another method ...

```
double[] ipp = { 0.255, 0.232, 0.618, 0.713 };
```

I'm trying to do so, but the array goes beyond the number of indices

```
for (int i = 0; i < ipp.Length; i++)
{
    if (ipp[i+1] > ipp[i]) // problem 
    {
        // ----> send this 
        //(ipp[i+1];ipp[i]) values 
        //to another method 
    }
}
```

Comment: i+1 goes out of bounds when processing the last item in the array. What should the last item in the array be compared to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the upper bound check in your `for` loop. When `i = ipp.Length - 1` and you access array item `ipp[i + 1]` you access an element outside of the array bounds, therefore the problem occurs.

You need to change upper bound check to the `i < ipp.Length - 1`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < ipp.Length - 1; i++)
{
    if (ipp[i + 1] > ipp[i])
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it really helped me, How simple a solution, but could not think of)
Maybe you can tell how to make the cycle work only with the next and previous element, and not with all the previous ones. I understand, it’s difficult. Here is a screenshot.
https://prnt.sc/saosde
https://prnt.sc/saosm1

The fact is that there is a tracing of extra lines.

Comment: It seems that extra line (2015-2017) appears not in the provided loop. Is there other code that can add data points?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I found an error. The problem was that I did not correctly form the points of X У.
Thank you very much for your help.